# How to fetch a string from a sub in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hta

In this example:

**TestSub.vbs**

```
a = "String"

TestSub a

Sub TestSub(a)

    MsgBox "Test " & a

End Sub
```

The Sub function works just fine and displays the text "*Test String*" in the MsgBox

But in this example (embedded in a HTA)

**TestSub2.VBS**

```
Sub getdata

    NameID = "name123"

    ' NameID = 123 ' (This works)

    strHTML0 = strHTML0 & _
    "<select>" & _
        "<option onclick='UpdateSelect("& NameID &")' language='vbscript'>" & _
            NameID & _
        "</option>" & _
    "</select>"

    SelectBox.innerHTML = strHTML0

End sub

Sub UpdateSelect(NameID)

    MsgBox "Test " & NameID

End sub
```

The `NameID` is displayed in the selectbox, but when you call the sub it doesn't display in the messagebox, however, if you set `NameID = 123` it displays the integer in the messagebox

Why can it only display integers and how can you make it display a string?

Posted whole .hta on **[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/FRR3ctJ3)**

Comment: you need to specify the `onclick` on the `select` not on the `option`

Comment: It didn't work, and I don't want the `onclick` event to fire everytime I click the selectbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating strings and must delimiter NameID value in this way:

```
"<option onclick='UpdateSelect("""& NameID &""")' language='vbscript'>" & _
```